# Sharing variables between Ruby classes within same module

Tags: ruby

I have module

```
# File 1.rb

module Search
  class A
    attr_accessor :results

    def find_results
      self.results = [somethings]
    end

    def do_something_with_results
      b = B.new.do_something
      b.response #=> something
      c = C.new.use_b_response_do_something
      return c.did_something
    end

  end
end


# File 2.rb

module Search
  class B

  end
  class C
  end
end
```

I have module `Search` with classes `A, B, C`
Class A does something and brings back data which needs to be shared with Classes B and C to do something with that data (refine it, send it somewhere, return true or false).

How can I share this information between the classes? I have been doing this which I think is wrong

```
def do_something
   b = B.new.doing_something
   c = C.new.something_else(b.some_attr)
end
```

which is not efficient

Comment: It's not really clear what your use case is, but you could try using inheritance. If `A`, `B`, and `C` all inherit from a common base class, you can use class variable, e.g. `@@my_class_variable` to share data between the classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues in your code. You seem to be doing things as it should be done. Using methods to get and pass data around.

One thing that could make your code better is passing b to c instead.

```
def do_something
    b = B.new.doing_something
    c = C.new(b).something_else
end
```

But it depends on  your use case...